# How do I make a link to a flag edit page?

Tags: 8, flags

I'm using Drupal 8 with Flag 4.0-beta1.

On my flag, I have several fields.  I want users to be able to edit these fields after making the flag.

How can I make a link to the flag edit page?

I [found this comment on using VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/flagging_form/issues/2185493) for Drupal 7, but on Drupal 8, VBO doesn't have the "modify entity" option for flaggings suggested in that post.

I tried various things in Views (making a view of flaggings; making a view of nodes with flaggings as a relationship), but I can't find a way to get an edit link.

EDIT: I got confused by the terminology and mixed up **flags** (the "type") and **flaggings** (the instance of the type) are different.  I'm leaving this question as is, and I [created a new question for flaggings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294643/how-do-i-make-a-link-to-a-flagging-edit-page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about any view field for an edit link, but you can link to the flag's edit screen, like most entities, in a number of ways.

Looking at the module's `flag.routing.yml` file, we see the edit route defined like:

```
entity.flag.edit_form:
  path: '/admin/structure/flags/manage/{flag}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: flag.edit
    _title: 'Edit Flag'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'flag.update'
```

The flag argument here is for the flag's id.

You can build out the link to the flag manually, e.g.

```
<a href='/admin/structure/flags/manage/MY_FLAG_ID'>Edit MY FLAG</a>
```

Or if you're working with twig, e.g. rewriting a view's field, make sure you're also including the flag's id in the view then rewrite doing something like:

```
<a href='/admin/structure/flags/manage/{{ flag_id }}'>{{ "Edit"|t }}</a>
```

Or you can [use PHP to build the url directly from the route](https://chromatichq.com/blog/how-link-dynamic-routes-drupal-8). It's recommended to use one of the following methods if you're working in PHP.

To get just the url text or object in PHP, use [Url::fromRoute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x):

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;

$my_flag_url_object = Url::fromRoute('entity.flag.edit_form', ['flag' => MY_FLAG_ID]);
// $my_flag_url_string returns something like "/admin/structure/flags/manage/123"
$my_flag_url_string = $my_flag_url_object->toString();
```

To build the whole link in PHP, use [Link::createFromRoute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/8.2.x):

```
use \Drupal\core\Link;

$my_flag_edit_link = Link::createFromRoute('MY FLAG EDIT TEXT', 'entity.flag.edit_form', ['flag' => MY_FLAG_ID]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer.  Unfortunately, I realized I was confused about the terms and looking for a link to the flagging edit page, not the flag edit page.  However, since you answered the question so extensively, I modified this question to match your answer and opened a new question here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294643/how-do-i-make-a-link-to-a-flagging-edit-page